# some issue with creating custom calendar table iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I created a custom calendar for my calendar app ... but I have some problem which I would be grateful if you help me to do this , this code shows a single day .
for example day 2  , 4 , 13 , 24

```
- (NSString *) showPersianDay {

    NSCalendar *persCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSPersianCalendar];    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *IRLocal = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa_IR"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:IRLocal];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:persCalendar];

    offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    offsetComponents.day = _dayNumber;

    NSDate *nextDate = [persCalendar dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d"];
    NSString *currDay = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currDay];

    [persCalendar release];
    [dateFormatter release];

    return currDay;
}
```

I created a custom table for a month which shows days of a month , so when user tap on this number my date should change according to the numbers ,

[image]

for example today is 4 Jan -- when user tap 6 Jan my date should change to the 6 Jan.

I don't have to use some way like : `day.text = @"6"` or something .... I need return a real DATE, How can I modify my code to show specific day ?
thank you.

Comment: how you get notified when the tap happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should have the class return an NSDictionary with multiple keys. One key can contain the string value for the day number, the other can contain the date object.

```
- (NSDictionary *) showPersianDay {

    NSCalendar *persCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSPersianCalendar];    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *IRLocal = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa_IR"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:IRLocal];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:persCalendar];

    offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    offsetComponents.day = _dayNumber;

    NSDate *nextDate = [persCalendar dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d"];
    NSString *currDay = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currDay];
    NSDictionary *results = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:currDay,@"dateString",nextDate,@"DateObj" nil];

    return results;
}
```

Then on the other side you can display the dateString and cache the DateObj in the calendar cell. Hopefully this solves your question.